montar una imagen de miktex para generar pdf
Relacionado con
podman montar imagen de miktex para generar pdf
Ahora esoty probando pero con docker
usé el comando
docker pull miktex/miktex
docker run -ti -v C:/miktex:/miktex/.miktex -v `pwd`:/miktex/work -e MIKTEX_UID=`-u ` miktex/miktex:essential pdflatex artex.tex

y esta es la salida:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
restricted \write18 enabled.


Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.


The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:


/var/lib/miktex/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log

el contenido del archivo es
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}

La imágen la hallé en https://hub.docker.com/r/miktex/miktex
Intentos
Revisión de logs
docker run -ti -v C:/miktex/work:/miktex/work -e MIKTEX_UID=`-u ` miktex/miktex:basic

miktex@0bd8d23765ec:/miktex/work$ ls


artex.tex

miktex@0bd8d23765ec:/miktex/work$xelatex artex.tex


This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (MiKTeX 23.10) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
restricted \write18 enabled.


Sorry, but xelatex did not succeed.


The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:


/var/lib/miktex/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/xelatex.log
miktex@0bd8d23765ec:/miktex/work$ cat /var/lib/miktex/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/xelatex.log

output:
2024-06-24 03:13:52,755Z INFO  xelatex - this process (34) started by bash in directory /miktex/work with command line: xelatex artex.tex
2024-06-24 03:13:52,755Z INFO  xelatex - this is MiKTeX-XETEX 4.10.0 (0.999995) (MiKTeX 23.10)
2024-06-24 03:13:52,756Z INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2024-06-24 03:13:52,805Z INFO  xelatex - going to create file: xelatex.fmt
2024-06-24 03:13:52,872Z INFO  xelatex.core - forking...
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z ERROR xelatex - /usr/bin/miktex did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z ERROR xelatex - output:
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z ERROR xelatex - Building format 'xelatex' with engine 'xetex'...

Sorry, but: The executed process did not succeed.

2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/TeXAndFriends/texmfapp.cpp:697
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/TeXAndFriends/texmfapp.cpp
2024-06-24 03:15:05,471Z FATAL xelatex - Line: 697
2024-06-24 03:15:05,476Z INFO  xelatex - this process (34) finishes with exit code 1
2024-06-24 03:15:05,478Z WARN  xelatex - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.

¿Hice algo mal?

Revisa la info del log: /var/lib/miktex/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log, que dice ahí?

actualizado junto con una prueba de xelatex, el caso de pdflatex es prácticamente el mismo log

No dice mucho el log lamentablemente, fijate si esto te da una pista: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1053
